# Adding a function to the passed this.props.onPress-function in a React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-props, touchableopacity

I have changed all the `TouchableOpacity`-components to a custom component so I can add a universal function to all the buttons / clickable views in my application. I call the new component `HapticButton`.

All the `HapticButton`-components will contain `onPress` properties like this:

```
<HapticButton activeOpacity={1.0} onPress={() => { console.log("button was pressed"); }}>...</HapticButton>
```

And my HapticButton-class looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';


export default class HapticButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={this.props.activeOpacity} style={[this.props.style]}  onPress={this.props.onPress}>
                    {this.props.children}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    vibrate() {
        // Code that makes a haptic feedback when called
    }
};
```

I succesfully pass on the `onPress`-property to my new `HapticButton`-component, but how do I merge together my the `this.props.onPress`-property with the `vibrate()`-function so that this gets called every time the `HapticButton` is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily merge two function call together as below

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
  this.props.onPress();
  this.vibrate();
}}>
```

or you can directly invoke `this.props.onPress()` in the `vibrate` function

```js
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.vibrate} ...

    vibrate() {
      this.props.onPress();
        // Code that makes a haptic feedback when called
    }
```

Not much differences based on your use case between the two ways I've shared, readability wise I think first way is better

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! I had tried similar solutions but always with this.props.onPress instead of this.props.onPress() and that did not work.